# Encoding of data from XML file and ASP.NET textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to compare a string obtained through a **textbox** and a string read from an **XML** file.
The **XML** file is as given below.

**<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>


<cars>


   <car>


          <name>


                Honda


           </name>


     </car>


</cars>**

The trouble is that when I compare the text "Honda" read from the XML file and the text obtained from the **textbox**, the comparison fails. I checked the length of both texts. The length of the text from the **textbox** is correctly shown while that from the XML file is 4 times larger. I'm wondering whether this has got something to do with the encoding of the texts. I'm not sure how we can make both text in the same format.

Any help would be great!

Thanks,

Comment: you didn't paste the XML, also would be helpful to see how you load/parse the XML

Answer (score 2):

With the XML that you pasted the value of name looks like `\n Honda \n` to me - remove all the white space and newlines from within your `<name>` tag and they should be identical.

Remember that all characters that are not markup will be passed to the application when you parse a node - in this case this includes the white space characters that are difficult to see and weed out sometimes, but they are there.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The newlines were the problem. That problem never crossed my mind.